# How do I dispose Bitmap / free memory after I got the requried data from BitmapMetadata?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I’m working on a solution,  which needs to support the query of many jpeg-files metadata to get the `Comment`- and `DateTaken`-Property. But I always get an OutOfMemoryException after about 20 files. So I need to know how I free the memory after I assigned the `Comment`- and `DateTaken`-values to the two strings. Currently I’m using a `JpegBitmapDecoder` and set the `BitmapCacheOption` by instantiation of the decoder to `OnLoad`. I think, that’s why I get the exception, but I don’t know how to make it better, since I work the first time with Images / Bitmaps.

In a separate form I have a BackgroundWorker, in which a method from the mainform is called. In that method two methods are called, to get the Comment and the DateTaken from the file. To get the metadata of the file in that two methods another method is called, in which I get the exception in the line, I instantiate the `JpegBitmapDecoder`.

Here are the methods:

In `formPleaseWait`:

```
private void bgwLoadPhotos_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 //BackgroundWorker in formPleaseWait
    {
        int filesCount;
        FileInfo[] files;

        FolderBrowserDialog browseFolder = (FolderBrowserDialog)e.Argument;

        files = selectedFolder.GetFiles("*.jpg");
        filesCount = files.Count();

        foreach (FileInfo file in selectedFolder.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
        {
            try
            {
                Photo photo = formMain.CreatePhotoObject(file);
        //the method in the mainform is called

                loadedPhotos.Add(photo);
                loadProgress++;

                if (loadProgress == filesCount)
                {
                    loadProgress = 100;
                }
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                loadProgress = 100;
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

In `formMain`:

```
    public Photo CreatePhotoObject(FileInfo file)
    {   

        int year = 0;
        string comment = GetPhotoComment(file);
        string dateString = GetPhotoDate(file);
        //the two methods to get comment and date are called
        string filename = file.Name;
        string path = selectedFolder + @"\" + filename;            
        string photoname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName);
        DateTime date = new DateTime();

        if(dateString != null)
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(dateString).Date;
            dateString = date.ToShortDateString();
            year = date.Year;
        }

        return new Photo(year, comment, filename, photoname, dateString);
    }

    private string GetPhotoComment(FileInfo file)
    {
        BitmapMetadata metadata = GetMetadata(file);

        return metadata.Comment;
    }

    private string GetPhotoDate(FileInfo file)
    {
        BitmapMetadata metadata = GetMetadata(file);

        return metadata.DateTaken;
    }

    private BitmapMetadata GetMetadata(FileInfo file)
    {
        BitmapFrame frame;
        BitmapMetadata metadata;
        JpegBitmapDecoder decoder;

        string filepath = file.FullName;

        using (Stream fileStreamIn = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open,  
               FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(fileStreamIn, 
                             BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                             BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            //Here I get the exception
        }

        frame = decoder.Frames[0];

        return metadata = (BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata;
    }
```

Comment: Please remove the cross-reference to the main form iout of Your form_wait , this is a basic rule. Use events to notify a main form, never ever pass a parent-reference to a child-form like You appearently did. And I do not see any background-worker in Your snippets.

Comment: "private void bgwLoadPhotos_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)"

That's my background-worker. It loads the files while a timer in another thread updates a progress bar. In the load-sequence of formWait I `RunWorkerAsync()` and then start the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I've created a class, which contains the needed methods:

```
 public class PhotoFactory
{
    [...]

    public Photo CreatePhotoObject(FileInfo file)
    {
        string comment;
        string dateString;
        DateTime date;

        int year = 0;
        string filename = file.FullName;
        string path = selectedFolder + @"\" + filename;
        string photoname = file.Name;

        GetCommentDate(file.FullName, out comment, out dateString);

        if (dateString != null)
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(dateString).Date;
            dateString = date.ToShortDateString();
            year = date.Year;
        }

        return new Photo(year, comment, filename, photoname, dateString);
    }

    private void GetCommentDate(string filepath, out string comment, out 
                                string dateString)
    {
        using (FileStream fileIn = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, 
               FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            BitmapSource source = BitmapFrame.Create(fileIn);
            BitmapMetadata metadata = (BitmapMetadata)source.Metadata;

            comment = metadata.Comment;
            dateString = metadata.DateTaken;
        }
    }
}
```

That way I don't get an OutOfMemoryException, when I load 100 files.

If anyone has improvement propasals or other annotations, I would appreciate to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't load the meta data twice. Your `GetPhotoComment` and `GetPhotoDate` methods should take a `BitmapMetadata` and not a `FileInfo`.

Then, you should try using `BitmapCacheOption.None`. Please see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption(v=vs.110).aspx) for the different available values.

Finally, all the methods from `formMain` that you showed us should be put in their own class. There is no reason why they are in a form class, they have nothing to do with the user interface. I would go about this in the following way:

1. Create a class `PhotoFactory` with a constructor with `selectedFolder` as a parameter.
2. Create an instance of that class inside `formMain` and pass it to `formPleaseWait`
3. Use that instance instead of `formMain`.

Comment: With `BitmapCacheOption.None` the required data from the `metadata`-property is null. In the documentation you linked it reads _"All requests for the image are filled directly by the image file."_  I think that's why the required data is null. So I need to know, how to get the data while `BitmapCacheOption` is `None` or if there is a completely different way to get the metadata. I know there are different Bitmap-classes like `Bitmap` oder `BitmapImage`, but since I'm quite new in software development and especially in work with Images / Bitmaps I need help to getting started with that classes.